# when I run this code it is showing error "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level", Why?

Tags: bots, telegram

When I run this code it shows an error like this. Why?
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
    from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 6364266
api_hash = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

with open("hash.txt", "r") as f:
    api_hash = f.read()
    

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print("{}{}".format(chat_id,chat))
    
   if chat_id == -1365145428:
   await client.send_message(-1519738140, event.raw_text)
   
    # chat_id == -1519738140:
    
    
    
    
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Please provide a full traceback

Comment: from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 6364266
api_hash = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

with open("hash.txt", "r") as f:
    api_hash = f.read()
    

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print("{}{}".format(chat_id,chat))
    
   if chat_id == -1365145428:
   await client.send_message(-1519738140, event.raw_text)
   
    # chat_id == -1519738140:
 
  
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()

Comment: I mean not code, but error traceback from python exception or any other logs.

Comment: but it looks like you have 4 extra spaces on first imports line

Comment: can you fix it?

Comment: Just remove first 4 spaces in your code and that's it.

Comment: it's not running.

Comment: It's not enough to say `it's not running`, please provide error messages, traceback and any other information that may help to solve you problem.

Comment: File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\Experiments folder\FWD Sript.py", line 18
    if chat_id == -1365145428:
                              ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 0):

To make it working you need to remove indentation for imports and add proper indentation (spaces) on the line with `if` statement and next one after that line:

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 6364266
api_hash = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

with open("hash.txt", "r") as f:
    api_hash = f.read()
    

client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
    chat = await event.get_chat()
    chat_id = event.chat_id
    print("{}{}".format(chat_id,chat))
    
    if chat_id == -1365145428:
        await client.send_message(-1519738140, event.raw_text)
   
        # chat_id == -1519738140:
    
    
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: @NARENDRASINGH please provide a traceback to your original question with initial error and with my solution. There shouldn't be any `IndentationError` if you copy-pasted that correctly (not edited your code).